# 45 degree tilt is shown, then it's immediately switched to 0 degree view, it's happening on some locations, why?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Here is the minimal working example:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      html, body, #map-canvas {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px
      }
    </style>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initialize() {

        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.743411, -121.93062500000002),
            tilt:45,
            zoom: 25,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
        };

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="map-canvas"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Try refresh it and very first map is shown with correct 45 degree tilt and then it's automatically within second switched to 0 degree view. Why is this happening? Apparently 45 degree maps for this location are available so why it's not displayed correctly? Somewhere it works as expected, somewhere it's bugged like this.

Comment: Does the google maps v3 api support tilting? Where are the controls that allow users to tilt the map?

Comment: the 45°-view isn't available for the entire world. Obviously it's not available for the given viewport, for a center of e.g. `37.743944,-121.950573` it works for me.

Comment: Yes of course, it's not supported everywhere, but why the very first map is 45 degree view and then it's immediately switched to 0 degree view? Try refresh it several times and you will see that 45 degree map is really rendered at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the given location definitely 45° imagery is available.

The decision if these images will be used will be done by the API, as it seems by calls to the viewportService(you'll see these calls in the network-tab)

I was able to get the 45°-view even for the given location by blocking call to `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js/ViewportInfoService*` via ABE(of course this is not a solution).

I can't tell you why google doesn't provide the 45°-view, maybe because of copyright(when you pan the map to the right until you see the 45°-view you will notice that the copyright-notice in the bottom-right corner changes).

I'm afraid you have to take it as it is.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [list of 45° imagery on Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?ll=8.787199,-45.827047&t=h&source=embed&dap&ie=UTF8&msa=0&spn=85.447389,153.703486&hl=en&mid=z3LmnfPRZzFk.kmewUZ7S-AVw), `new google.maps.LatLng(37.743411, -121.93062500000002)` isn't supported yet. However, I too, can see what is happening. It is rending the tilt image then it goes back. However, it only happens when you set `heading: 0`, heading with 45 and 90 seems to have the same image... so I can only say they are still preparing the 45° imagery this location.

Comment: this doesn't seem to be a complete list